# BeautifulSoup find class return none

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am using `BeautifulSoup` and python writing code to scraping information from website, after I try to get particular content by 'class' category, it return "[ ]", is this means 'none'?

is that means it has nothing to scraping?

following is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.metservice.com/towns-cities/locations/auckland/7-days')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find_all(class_='IconWithText-content')

print(week)
```

Comment: Very strange, I found the class with the text you need from the site, but it doesn't show up in the response.text, could be protection against web scraping, but I don't see why a weather service would do that.

Comment: Yes, I just learned it from a tutorial by using example of AMAZON website, which was working just fine, I do surprise to see a weather service do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The issue is page content are not loaded while you are trying to **scrape**,*

*You can use `selenium` with `BeautifulSoup`*

*Example*

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.metservice.com/towns-cities/locations/auckland/7-days"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find_all(class_='IconWithText-content')
print(week)
```

Comment: I think it because of what you saying,  the contents are in Javascript which can not scrap by html method, I have used your code above but it not that simple, I will google and learn how to install and other staff to make selenium work. thanks, and appreciate it.

Comment: @D1ag0 no problem, there is a lot examples on this site, if run into issue just post new question- good luck and have fun

Answer (score 2):

`selenium` is a good idea. But, if you want good user interface, you can download the file from the web, read it, then delete it like this:

```
import wget
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

wget.download('https://www.metservice.com/towns-cities/locations/auckland/7-days', "tmp.html")
with open('tmp.html') as week_html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(week_html, 'html.parser')
os.remove('tmp.html')
week = soup.find_all(class_='IconWithText-content')

print(week)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the actual html returned by that request, you'll find there's no element with `class` of `IconWithText-content` in there, so you won't find it.

What you did would work, or this:

```
soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'IconWithText-content'})
```

Comment: Thanks, but it  might be my problem that I still have the problem with your suggest code above. appreciate your help.