# Google Dictionary result scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the google's dictionary result but I think I'm doing some mistake. Here's the screenshot of the content I'm trying to scrape:

[image: 1]

Here's the code I'm running :

```py
elif 'meaning' in query:
          query = query.replace("what", "").replace("meaning", "").replace("means", "").replace("is the", "").replace("of","")
          headers = {
            'User-agent':
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
          }
          r = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}", headers=headers)
          soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

          result = soup.find('div', class_= 'LTKOO sY7ric')
          print(result.span.text)
          speak(result.span.text)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\MY Programmes\DUSTIN- THE VOICE ASSISTANT\dustin.py", line 106, in <module>
    print(result.span.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the page is not loaded yet when you try `soup.find(query)` so you can either do `time.sleep(x)` or use wget to download the page and use soup to query that once it's downloaded.

Source: [BeautifulSoup find class return none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61313517/beautifulsoup-find-class-return-none)